# Project visualization in Lisp

Tags: lisp, visualization

Is there a tool that can generate diagrams (similar to Doxygen using Graphviz) but in the formats described by this paper: [Lisp Looks Different](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Dozs08aLispLooksDifferent.pdf)

**Program Style Distribution:** Determine which programming style (Functional, OO, Imperative or Macro) dominates a software package, also to determine the size of complexity in each package.

[image: Program Style Distribution]

**Class Method Relation View:** Visualizes the relationships between classes and methods (in Lisp, classes and methods are separated). The goal is to identify possible independent or loosely coupled components of the system.

[image: Class Method Relation View]

**Generic Concer View:** Helps to identify and locate cross-cutting concerns associated with generic functions. 
[image: Generic Concern View]

**Class Type View:** Helps to identify different types of classes, based on their structure, more precisely on the attributes to methods ratio.
tio

[image: Class Type View]

For the meaning of the colors and shapes, please refer to the document. It would be nice if there are equivalent tools for other languages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Mondrian](http://www.moosetechnology.org/tools/mondrian), which the paper cites was what was used to generate those diagrams?

More generally, have you looked at [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org/), of which Mondrian is but a part?

I'm not sure I've seen one that produces diagrams exactly like those above, but there are quite a few [more](http://vidi.cs.ucdavis.edu/research/softvis) [software](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/ii/softvis/ooviz/ooviz.html) [visualization](http://xray.inf.usi.ch/xray.php) [tools](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/wettel/codecity.html) [around](http://xplrarc.massey.ac.nz/index.jsp).

Comment: Thanks. I missed the Mondrian part. The other visualization tools are very nice.

Comment: Btw, this is also the first time I heard about Moose.

Answer (score 0):

Obvous first step: contact the paper's authors and ask what tools they used, and do they have any code they can share.

Comment: Well but I don't want to wait forever :)